# Error accured in get_money() function

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>  
#include <iomanip>  
int main ()
{
   long double price;
   std::cout << "Please, enter the price: ";
   std::cin >> std::get_money(price);

   if (std::cin.fail()) std::cout << "Error reading price\n";
   else std::cout << "The price entered is: " << price << '\n';

   return 0;
}
```

I am getting error forlling error while compiling the above program.

getmoney.cpp: In function `int main()':
getmoney.cpp:10: error:`get_money' is not a member of `std'.

get_money is the predefined function. I don't know why i am receiving this error.

Comment: How do you compile your code? With which version of which compiler? With which compiler arguments (you may need `-std=c++11`)? [std::get_money](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/get_money/) is a C++11 addition

Comment: Did you `#include <iomanip>`?

Comment: I seem to be having problems with `get_money` all the time...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you included `iomanip`but nevertheless the compiler issues an error it means that your compiler does not support C++ 2011 standard or you did not select such an option of the compiler.

Comment: How I can change my compiler to support C++2011 standard?

Comment: @Jeyamaran I do not know whar compiler you are using but you can either to search here a similar question or ask your own question.

Answer (score 1):

Did you include the header "iomanip" in your code?

Comment: Try not answering with a question. *Including `iomanip` as a header might work* would have been a better way of answering.

Answer (score 0):

Wen you have such problem go to check on a reference website such as http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/get_money/

and you will see that

```
This manipulator is declared in header <iomanip>.
```

and you even often have an example code which show you how to use it.

So including *iomanip* may solve your problem

If that is not working, you are probably using an older compiler which does not support C++ 11. And therefore you could simply not use this function without changing your compiler.

Comment: Then check that your compiler support C++11 because the page i gave you also explicit (the little yellow warning triangle besides the function name) that it is only supported by C++11